# Accidently deletetd .ecryptfs folder - cant log in anympre

Tags: login, ecryptfs, restore, data-recovery

I accidently deleted the .ecryptfs folder, also the .private folder. Cant login anymore. Just as guest. How can I restore to the system before I deletetd those fodlers?

Answer (score 2):

Did you record your randomly generated mount passphrase?  It would be 16 or 32 characters of [0-9a-f].  If you have that long, random passphrase, it's relatively easy to recover.  If you don't have that, there's no chance of recovery.

If you have your randomly generated mount passphrase, you'll recreate your .ecryptfs directory.

```
mkdir $HOME/.ecryptfs
ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
[enter your long, random mount passphrase]
keyctl list @u
[add the two key fingerprints to $HOME/.ecryptfs/Private.sig]
ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase $HOME/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
echo $HOME > $HOME/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt
```

Comment: I only can log in as Guest. Im not allowed to make a directory. Sudo doesnt work. It says:  unable to change to sudoers gid

Comment: You'll need to boot the system from a live cd, then.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

When I enter

    ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase $HOME/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase

I get 

    Error: Wrapping passphrase failed [-5]
    Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs

Comment: I don't recommend doing this from live CD. You can still login as your normal user using the Console (Ctrl+Alt+F1)

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can restore your drive is to have the mount passphrase, which is a 16, 32, or 64 character string provided to you at the time of encryption. If you did not save that string, your data is lost. To make the walk-through easier, we assume you created a new file called `/home/USER/mountkey` and stored the above passphrase in there. In the bash snippets below, replace `USER` with your username.

If you have that passphrase, here are the steps:

```
mkdir /home/USER/.ecryptfs
touch /home/USER/.ecryptfs/Private.sig
ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
```

You will be asked to enter the passphrase. Upon doing so, you will be provided with two sig keys. Store the two keys in two separate lines in `/home/USER/.ecryptfs/Private.sig` (If you missed these keys, you can retrieve them by running `keyctl list @u`).

Now, run the following:

```
cat /home/USER/mountkey <(echo "ORIGINAL_PASSWORD") | ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase /home/USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

In the above, the ORIGINAL_PASSWORD is whatever password you originally used to encrypt your hard drive. There is good chance you used the same password as your login password, but this is not necessarily true. The ORIGINAL_PASSWORD is also different from the passphrase stated in the beginning which is a 16, 32, or 64 alphanumerical string.

Now you need to specify where to mount your home drive, and to activate automatic mounting:

```
/home/USER/ > /home/USER/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt
touch /home/USER/.ecryptfs/auto-mount
touch /home/USER/.ecryptfs/auto-umount
```